# How can I connect to multiple db schemas? (C# / MySQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I've created a class that confirms if it's able to connect to a db on mysql using login info provided via string CadenaConexion. How can I process an additional db and have the code connect to both when executing?

First I create a connection and assign the login info (here is where I'd add the second db):

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace DBManager
{
public class DBConexion
{
    protected MySqlConnection oConexion;
    String CadenaConexion = "Server=localhost; Port=3306;Database=blabla;Uid=root;Pwd=blabla; AllowZeroDateTime=True;"; 
    string _estado;
    public string Estado
    {
        get => _estado;

    }
```

Then I determine if connected or not through a boolean variable:

```
    public Boolean Conectar()
    {
        Boolean Conectado = false;
        oConexion = new MySqlConnection(CadenaConexion);
        try
        {
            oConexion.Open();
            Conectado = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            Conectado = false;
        }

        _estado = oConexion.State.ToString();
        return Conectado;
    }
```

Optional method to confirm if successful, as it will not perform the disconnect unless it was previously connected:

```
    public void Desconectar()
    {
        try
        {

            if (oConexion.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                try
                {
                    oConexion.Close();
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }

            _estado = oConexion.State.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            _estado = "Indefinido";
        }

    }
```

Comment: So swap out the database name to a different one in the connection string?

Comment: Yes, but I want to connect to both at the same time while the program is running. I'd like to add a second string entry but not sure how...

Comment: So make a second connection with the second connection string.....